# Expand a matrix by given a parameter K, by inserting zeros in its between its original elements

Tags: matlab, matrix, expand

Suppose I have a matrix `A` of size `3-by-3`:

```
A = [a11, a12, a13; a21, a22, a23; a31, a32, a33];
```

Then I specify a parameter `K`, saying `K` is 2, then what I want is to make `A` become

```
a11  0  0  a12  0 0  a13  0  0
 0   0  0   0   0 0   0   0  0
 0   0  0   0   0 0   0   0  0
a21  0  0  a22  0 0  a23  0  0
 0   0  0   0   0 0   0   0  0
 0   0  0   0   0 0   0   0  0
a31  0  0  a32  0 0  a33  0  0
 0   0  0   0   0 0   0   0  0
 0   0  0   0   0 0   0   0  0
```

where, I insert `K` rows and columns of zeros between the original elements.

Is there any official function to do it in MATLAB?

Answer (score 2):

For square matrix, A

**Code**

```
%%// Parameter
K = 3; 

[x1,y1] = meshgrid(0:size(A,1)-1,0:size(A,1)-1)

x1 = bsxfun(@times,x1,K)+1
y1 = bsxfun(@times,y1,K)+1

Anew = zeros(size(A)*K)
Anew(sub2ind(size(Anew),y1(:),x1(:)))=A
```

Answer (score 2):

Two alternative methods

Indexing:
initalise `out` as zeros and then fill in the required elements using indexing

```
out=zeros(size(A)*(K+1));
out(1:K+1:end,1:K+1:end)=A
```

Kronecker tensor product:
generate a matrix to multiply each element with, then use `kron` function

```
temp=zeros(K+1),temp(1)=1
out=kron(A,temp)
```

Comment: Thankyou, I was tempted to play with sparse to build it too but couldnt find an elegant way,

Comment: Sparse would be too much for this simple task I guess. One can also play with cell arrays I think, but again might be loads of work.

Comment: kind of overkill I know, but just to build the matrix then cast back to full, e.g. using the variables from your answer `full(sparse(x1,y1,A,9,9))`

Comment: Kool! It works with a fix that `x1` and `y1` are to be interchanged, little weird thing about how `meshgrid` outputs results. OP already has handful of approaches at his disposal!